# Selecting number in column "x" randomly to achieve desired number

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers in a column (i.e., 1 to 10 in column A) and a few numbers in another column (i.e six numbers in column E).

I want to place numbers of column E in column B randomly, so that absolute difference between An and Bn is more than my desirable number (D1).

I used RandomSelection function:

```
Function RandomSelection(aRng As Range)
Dim index As Integer
Randomize
index = Int(aRng.Count * Rnd + 1)
RandomSelection = aRng.Cells(index).Value
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You know that it is not possible, if X is between 2 and 5 it is not possible to find a number between 1 and 6 that when subtracted is greater than your desired number of 5, what then?

Comment: also this can be done with a formula, no need for vba.

Comment: if X is between 2 and 5, To prevent this problem we put in column E between 4 and 10 definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$2:$E$7/(ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)>=$D$1),RANDBETWEEN(1,SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)>=$D$1))))
```

I changed the numbers in E2:E7 so it would return values that are greater.  As stated in the comments.  Getting numbers 1-6 to work with 1-10 left many errors as one cannot find a number 1-6 that returns a number greater than 5 with an `X` of 2-5.

[image]

Comment: Scott, the OPs comment to me below is "I want to every number in range (c2:c21) be less than D1", and in his question he states "so that absolute difference between An and Bn is more than my desirable number (D1)", It can't be both, i'm not sure the OP knows what he wants.

Comment: @GMalc I agree, I just had this done last night, but forgot to hit post.  I liked it so I posted it.  If I am wrong, then I will delete.

Comment: So you want it between 0 and the Value in D1?  First if this answered your question as is then please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Second new questions get new post.  Make sure you link to this one and show what you attempted to modify to get your desired result.  @alirezataghizadeh

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. This screenshot was just an example, but my job is different That formula could solve my problem.
Now I want to be  ABS($E$2:$E$7-A2)>$D$1>0 , I used  َAnd function; but did not run

Comment: @alirezataghizadeh see my last comment, this answered this question, as a new question and mark this correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  This forum is different than others, new questions get new posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by using `RANDBETWEEN` and `ABS` Formulas.

```
Dim RndmzRng As Range
Set RndmzRng = Range("B2:B21")

Dim AbsValRng As Range
Set AbsValRng = Range("C2:C21")

Dim cel As range

    With ActiveSheet
        RndmzRng.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,6)" 'so you don't need data in ColE
        'can be use with cell references, "=RANDBETWEEN($E$2,$E$3") where E2=1 and E3=6
        AbsValRng.Formula = "=ABS(B2-A2)" 'Absolute formula

        For Each cel In AbsValRng 'colors the cells green that are > the value in Range("D1")
            If cel.Value > Range("D1").Value Then
                cel.Value = cel.Value - Range("D1").Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: I want to every number in range (c2:c21) be less than D1
<Sub bbbb()
Dim i As Integer
Dim AbsValRng As Range
Set AbsValRng = Range("C1:C21")
Dim RndmzRng As Range
Set RndmzRng = Range("B1:B21")
Dim cel As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        RndmzRng.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,6)"
        AbsValRng.Formula = "=ABS(RC[-2]-RC[-1])"
    End With
End Sub>